# Setting up hotspot with hostapd & udhcpd on wlan0 with internet on eth0

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, internet, dhcp

[Ubuntu 12.04]

I am trying to achieve a simple configuration that uses the Internet from eth0 and sets up a hot-spot on wlan0. But my requirements has constraint of not using NetworkManager. And I am using udhcpd & udhcpc in place of dhcpd & dhclient as I later need to replicate it on embedded environment.

I have tried various configurations for NAT as well as bridging but does not seem to work. Therefore, I am formulating my issue here.

1) I have disabled Network Manager from startup.

2) I connect to Internet using following commands:

```
ifconfig eth0 up
udhcpc -i eth0

My network has a proxy server that I have entered in Network > Network Proxy > Manual.(This is not expected in embedded environment)
```

I am able to access the Internet with above configuration on system.

3) I start hostapd on wlan0 using following commands:

```
hostapd -B hostapd.conf
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.50.1
udhcpd udhcpd.conf
```

hostapd.conf contains:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
ssid=laptop-open
hw_mode=g
channel=1
auth_algs=1
ieee80211n=1
```

udhcpd.conf contains:

```
start 192.168.50.10
end 192.168.50.20
max_leases 10
lease_file udhcpd.leases
interface wlan0
opt dns 192.168.50.1
opt subnet 255.255.255.0
opt router 192.168.50.1
```

I am able to see this on a wi-fi station and also able to connect to it.

I need to route the Internet to this station device from eth0 source.

I have tried both option stated at: https://code.google.com/p/quickanddirty/wiki/CreatingWirelessHotspotWithLinux
with slight variations as this link uses dhcp & dmsmasq in place of udhcpd & udhcpc.

Any pointers or explanation would be much help.

Comment: I successfully used ap-hotspot (see http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html) although it says it's deprecated. The original info is from http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2009381

Comment: I followed all the steps. All the steps were success. However, I am still not getting Internet on the Wi-Fi station. I am not sure but cout routing be the issue? I get following on route -n : `Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.34.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.10.34.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.150.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
`